# Running code without ssh in beaglebone black

Tags: ssh, login, startup, bashrc, beagleboneblack

**I want to run some code in `Beaglebone black` without doing `ssh` when I apply power.**

I have tried putting some commands to run the code in `~/.bashrc` file but it only works when I login using `ssh`. I have tried same thing with `/etc/rc.local` file but didn't work even after ssh.

I have also tried `@reboot my_command`  in `crontab -e` but it also requires me to login using ssh.

Any suggestions??

EDIT:

```
root@beaglebone:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie

root@beaglebone:~# ps aux | grep cron | grep -v grep
root       295  0.0  0.3   4428  1988 ?        Ss   15:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
```

Output of `crontab -e`: last few lines

```
root@beaglebone:~# crontab -e
    # For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
    #
    # m h  dom mon dow   command


#@reboot /root/wiringBone-master/library/main           not working

#*/5 * * * * /root/wiringBone-master/library/main       works
```

`main` is the script I want to run

```
root@beaglebone:~# systemctl enable cronie.service
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
```

Permission and owner of `main`

```
root@beaglebone:~/wiringBone-master/library# ll main 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 66744 May 27 16:15 main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crontab is the solution. Invoke by:

```
crontab -e
```

Which will open the default editor. Add:

```
@reboot your command
```

Save and exit. If the command requires superuser password, you should first `sudo su -`, and `crontab -e` as root.

In order to get to the very source of the problem (whether it is cron or the script), a simpler case may be created for debugging purposes:

- First a line such as `@reboot date >> /root/a` or similar is added as a cron job after `crontab -e`
- If it works ( ~ appends date/time to file "/root/a"), that line is saved into a bash script with the same ownership and permissions (`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root`) and such as:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/sh
  date >> /root/a
  ```

Comment: Will it execute my script without login into BBB ??

Comment: Surely. I use it to connect my Rpi to openvpn at reboot, without my login

Comment: I have to ssh for `crontab -e` to execute my script at startup. not working

Comment: Did you crontab as a non-root user or root? If the script requires sudo privileges, it has to be crontabbed as root. And for the first time to enter the cron job, you have to ssh once. What is your exact situation? Can't you ever ssh?

Comment: I can ssh . I'm running Debin 7.8 in BBB and login as `root` when I edited `crontab -e` so I have all the privileges I guess.

Comment: Are there any environment variables referred to in the scripts that are only introduced in the .bashrc of a user but not in /etc/environment? Root will not recognize those variables.

Comment: No environment variables. I'm able to run the code without `crontab`.

Comment: Which distro do you use in BBB? Can you please execute: `ps aux | grep cron | grep -v grep` You may have to enable cron by: `systemctl enable cronie.service` . Another silly point is that, sometimes the last line of the crontab file is not read, could you please add an extra line of one whitespace after your line

Comment: Added all those things you asked for.

Comment: According to `ps`, cron is already running, so no problem with its initialization. And you say, the job can run once in every 5 minutes without requiring your explicit action, automatically, but not at startup/reboot? This is really weird. Which user is the owner of the script and what are the rwx permission levels?

Comment: Added at the end of Q

Comment: No problem with the file permissions, no problem with cron itself. Do you uncomment the job line while trying to run it? It is commented above.

Comment: After trying those command I commented out those two lines.

Comment: Could you please provide a very simple task to crontab, first a line such as `@reboot date >> /root/a` or similar and then if it works (appends date/time to file "a"), putting that line into a bash script with the same ownership and permissions. I'm trying to understand the root cause by simplifying, is it sth about cron or your script.

Comment: `@reboot date >> /root/a`  worked and I manege to get my script run with crontab using @reboot. Thanks your last comment helped me to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @Sarhat: Please edit your answer so that I can upvote.

Comment: You're welcome, my pleasure. What exactly was wrong, so that I can edit my answer.

Comment: my sript requires some overlay (`.dtbo` files, some BBB thing )for proper execution so I also added them in `crontab -e` and it worked. What actually help is your `@reboot date >> /root/a` it really helped me to debug this whole thing. Add that in your answer.

Comment: I did so, in two bullet points.